# How do I redirect the user to another webpage after saving a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page where, when a link is clicked on, it generates a text file and prompts the "Save As" dialog box for the user to save the file.  Then I want to automatically redirect the user to another web page once the file has been saved.  The code below works in Chrome (saves file and redirects) but in Firefox it only prompts the file to be saved and doesn't redirect.  I've tried viewing the page in a debugger in Firefox and I don't see anything wrong.  This used to work in Firefox and now it doesn't anymore.  Any help is appreciated.  TIA!.

I'm using ColdFusion and JavaScript/Jquery.  I'm not well versed in Javascript/Jquery so I came up with the code below by doing research online on examples I found.

```
<cfinclude template="_a_PrintBadge.cfm">

<form name="backToAdmin" action="<cfoutput>admin.cfm?#session.URLToken#&session.user=#session.user#&smartscan=#trim(ID)#&ID=#trim(ID)#&printed=yes</cfoutput>" method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="record" value="#record#">

  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    //convert coldfusion variables to java variables
    <cfoutput>
      var #toScript(record, "recordToPrint")#;
    </cfoutput>

    $("#save-btn").click(function() {

      //if balance due then only generate file if correct password entered
      <cfif val(balanceDue) gt 0>                
        <cfoutput>if(document.checkPrint.overridePassword.value != 'printme^^')
          return;
        </cfoutput>
      </cfif>

      //assign record created
      var blob = new Blob([recordToPrint], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});

       //get timestamp for file name
       var d = new Date();
       var hours = d.getHours();
       var mins = d.getMinutes();
       var secs = d.getSeconds();
       var str1 = 'BADGE';
       var filename = str1 + '_' + hours + mins + secs + '.txt';

       //Generate file to save
       saveAs(blob, filename);

       //Send back to admin search page
       document.backToAdmin.submit();

   });

</script>

</form>

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: so what does the Firefox Developer Tools console say? Any errors, or warnings, or...?

Comment: When I run the page where this code resides, I get this error "ReferenceError: reference to undefined property "triggered" for the  jquery-3.3.1.js file that I'm calling in the file.  I'm calling this in the file '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'

Comment: please show that error in your post, so that others can see what you're seeing.